# Message is not refreshing in Push Notification

Tags: android

My problem is that I am able to get notifications from server but the message which is coming from server is not refreshing in my mobile whatever notification is coming first time the same message I am getting all the time . Here is my code of C2DMMessageReceiver & 
MessageReceivedActivity is as follows .

```
   public class C2DMMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.w("C2DM", "Message Receiver called");
        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {
            Log.w("C2DM", "Received message");
            final String payload = intent.getStringExtra("payload");
            createNotification(context, payload);
        }
    } 
    public void createNotification(Context context, String payload) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                "Message received", System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageReceivedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("payload", payload);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                intent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Message",
                "New message received", pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }

}

public class MessageReceivedActivity extends Activity 
 {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {

String message = extras.getString("payload");


if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {

TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

view.setText(message);

}

}

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
}
```

Comment: can you provide more code ? like where you put this code ? "onCreate" or onResume and what type of PUSH you did ?

Comment: ok diagor can u send me ur email id ????

Answer (score 0):

As i can see it your problem is the cache ...

for example in my server using php i use this header before i send anything for output :

```
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

hope this to help you

best regards,
Vangelis

Comment: Hello, 

this is not in the android side ... i use this code in my server side using php for my needs ...

i guess you use your android app to request data from a remote server right ?

if yes you should put this on the top of the file that you send the response (if you use php) if you use another language (asp.net C# etc) you should search on internet about caching techniques for your  server language ...

hope this to help you

best regards,
Vangelis

Answer (score 0):

as I see you need to register the C2DMMessageReceiver in your activity try to override the onResume() method and register the Receiver on this Intent "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".